# Can't perform chi-squared test statistic of OLS regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, inference, scipy.stats

it's my first time here and I'm new to programming.

I regressed a column of my df against another with stats.linregress and I'm trying to evaluate the goodness of fit with the Chi Square Statistic test, and I tried 2 methods, scipy.stats.chi2_contingency() and scipy.stats.chisquare(), problem is I can't get frequencies from the columns that are readable by the methods (this is what I think anyway).

The code is:

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import scipy
    from scipy import stats

    df3 = pd.read_csv('MODELLO RAVASI-MARK UP shock1+control-table.csv', thousands=',')
    df_cntrl_reg = df3.loc [(df3['time'] > 34) & (df3['wageShock'] == 1) &     
    (df3['wageSchockTime']==30)]
    

    x = df_cntrl_reg.time
    y = df_cntrl_reg.profits
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
    stats.linregress(x,y)
```

output:LinregressResult(slope=57.735721968728164, intercept=-1788.6653717798467, rvalue=0.014085574855596942, pvalue=0.47927072225571066, stderr=81.59589542103119)

```
    df_cntrl_reg['predicted'] = 57.735721968728164*df_cntrl_reg.time -1788.6653717798467
    obs = df_cntrl_reg['profits'].value_counts()
    exp = df_cntrl_reg['predicted'].value_counts()
    scipy.stats.chisquare(f_obs = obs, f_exp = exp, ddof = 1)
```

But there I get
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2525,) (25,

I tried to apply the method .ravel() like this:

```
    obs = df_cntrl_reg['profits'].value_counts().ravel()
    exp = df_cntrl_reg['predicted'].value_counts().ravel()
```

But this didn't change anything.

I tried to use  scipy.stats.chi2_contingency():

```
    table = [df_cntrl_reg['predetti'], df_cntrl_reg.profits]
    scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(table)
```

but i get ValueError: All values in `observed` must be nonnegative.

I also tried this to get the table:

```
   to_test = df_cntrl_reg[['profits', 'predetti']]
   table = to_test.apply(pd.Series.value_counts(bins=10))
```

but i get TypeError: value_counts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Can you help me with an easy way to get the statistic? I don't need to use the methof itself,
simply to obtain the statistic, I can get the p-value from the tables. I'm using python 3 on jupiter
notebook and my OS is win 10 (I know I know, but until very recently I've never needed to program anything).
Thanks in advance